# Passar valores para 99 campos num loop

Tags: c#, .net, variáveis

Gostaria de passar valores para 99 campos num *loop*;

Por exemplo:

```
for(int i=1; i<= 99 ; i++)
{
    nomedocampo + "i" = "valorqualquer";
}
```

Comment: Quais campos, pergunta falta contexto?

Comment: são labels com o mesmo nome porém com o número de 1 a 99 concatenado

Comment: É um WPF? Mvc? Winforms? Dependendo do ambiente dá pra utilizar métodos de "find control" que facilitaria sua vida. Ou dependendo seria necessário utilizar `Reflection`

Comment: Web application

Answer (score 6, accepted):

O problema apresentado não deve ser resolvido assim, existe um mecanismo simples e básico que chama-se *array*. Com ele você faz o que deseja da forma simples e correta, com boa performance e sem chances de erros. Isto pode ser usado em qualquer cenário, inclusive nos citados em comentários nesta página.

Não importa o que queria fazer esta é a solução correta. Não é que seja uma alternativa melhor, qualquer outra forma muito diferente disto é um completo absurdo. Usar reflexão para algo tão básico é provavelmente o pior erro que já vi usando reflexão porque tem algo melhor em todos os sentidos possíveis.

A solução com dicionário não é um absurdo para alguns casos (embora o código poderia ser melhor), mas não é boa para este, o *array* simples resolve melhor. O que pode ser usado no lugar do *array* é uma lista, aí depende se pode ter um número variado de campos ou não.

Olha que simples:

```
using static System.Console;

public class Program {
    public static void Main() {
        var objeto = new Classe();
        for (int i = 0; i < 99 ; i++) objeto.campos[i] = "valorqualquer" + i;
        foreach (var item in objeto.campos) WriteLine(item);
    }
    public class Classe {   
        public string[] campos = new string[99];
    }
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/xDb1mu). E no [**.NET Fiddle**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/k9Jdq7). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Class/MultipleFields.cs).

Obviamente cada variável individual do *array* (seus elementos) pode ser acessada diretamente com o número dela e não precisa usar uma variável, então em vez de ter `campo1` terá `campo[1]`, só isto.

Answer (score 2):

No C# você não consegue criar variáveis com nomes dinâmicos por conta da linguagem ser fortemente tipada. O que você pode fazer é criar um array com esses campos, a forma recomendada pela MICROSOFT é que você utiliza um dicionário, conforme link: [Dicionário MICROSFOT](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.dictionary-2?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.8).

Segue exemplo de criação de um dicionário:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace QuickTest
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Dictionary<string, int> names = new Dictionary<string,int>();


            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
            {
                names.Add(String.Format("name{0}", i.ToString()), i);
            }

            var xx1 = names["name1"];
            var xx2 = names["name2"];
            var xx3 = names["name3"];
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: obrigado pela resposta! Então, na verdade esses 99 campos já existem,eles possuem o mesmo nome porém com o número de 1 a 99 concatenado. O que eu preciso fazer é passar valores utilizando um loop sem ter que fazer esse procedimento 99x.

Comment: No caso, você não conseguirá atribuir em uma variável, o C# não permite esse tipo de atribuição. Você teria que criar o array ou o dicionário. Com o array você consegue atribuir os valores da seguinte forma: names["name" + i] = 'batata';

Comment: Ele não precisa **criar** as variáveis, apenas alterar o valor das que estão criadas. Isso é possível utilizando `Reflection`